# 適応 vs 同化 for adaptation

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nuances, expressions, word-usage

Which word is better for expression meaning of my adaptation to environment, situation or person, which I don't like, but unable to change situation, stop or influence situation in anyway.

For example, noise from neighbors.
Some neighbors have their dog constantly barking. Some neighbors have very noisy washing machine and wash their cloth every evening. Some neighbors watch TV very loudly. Some neighbors ... etc.

When I moved to this apartment, all these noises made me sick and ware very painful. Any negotiations lead to nothing. I wanted to move next month. But 2 weeks later, I found that despite all these noises are still there (dog is still barking, washing machine is still working), but they do not make me sick and do not make me pain anymore. Of course I prefer there would be no dog nor washing machine noise, but now I do not plan to move to new apartment, just because of these noises. My body and soul are ADOPTED to situation, which I still cannot influence and change in anyway. Simply speaking, now I can live with that.

If  I want to describe my situation something like this:
**inside adaptation is better than outside resistance**
which word for adaptation is better 適応 or 同化 or maybe there is some other word for ADAPTATION?

Comment: Your description of the change ("I found that" all these noises no longer cause distress), makes it sound as if you have not so much **adapted** to this environment as **gotten used to it** or **grown accustomed to it** (or perhaps **become impervious to it**). The difference is that "adapted," in this context, would imply conscious effort and action (such as using earplugs, taking up meditation, or just consciously trying not to let the noise affect you), while those other alternatives would not. Clarifying this point may help you get a better answer. (Either way 同化 doesn't really fit.)

Answer (score 1):

Today I finally met the word, which I think the best fits to the situation of my question and this word is:

順応 (じゅんのう)